# How to iterate over JSON object collection (not array) in Perl?

Tags: linux, files, perl, json

I'm learning Perl. I have been able to successfully iterate over a JSON collection when the objects were contained in an array. However, I cannot understand how to work with JSON data where the objects are not in an array and have random identifiers (e.g., `0y7vfr1234`) which are **not known in advance**. Here's some example data with the structure I'm attempting to read, update and save back to a file.

```
{
    "0y7vfr1234": {
        "username": "user1@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password123",
        "uri": "ww1.example.com",
        "index": 14
    },
    "v2rbz1568": {
        "username": "user3@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password125",
        "uri": "ww3.example.com",
        "index": 29
    },
    "0zjk1156": {
        "username": "user2@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password124",
        "uri": "ww2.example.com",
        "index": 38
    }
}
```

If these objects were all inside an array, I would do it similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib qw(..);
use JSON;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename1 = 'input.json';
my $filename2 = 'serverlist.txt';

my $json_text = do {
open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename1)
    or die("Can't open \$filename1\": $!\n");
local $/;
<$json_fh>
};

open my $server_list, '<', $filename2 or die "Can't open $filename2: $!";
my @server_list = <$server_list>;
close $server_list or die "Can't close $server_list: $!";

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

my $aref = $data->{the_array_name};

for my $setting (@$aref) {
    if (length $setting->{uri}) { #no warnings
        $setting->{uri} =~ m/^ww(\d+)\.example.com/;
        my $server_number = $1;
        print "checking $server_number ... \n";
        if (grep{/$setting->{uri}/} @server_list) {
            print "server number is:  $server_number\n";
        } else {
            # 1. iterate through the sorted list
            foreach (@server_list)
            {
                $_ =~ m/^ww(\d+)\.example.com/;
                my $new_num = $1;
                # 2. find the next match in order
                if ( $new_num > $server_number ) {
                    print "Found it: new server number $new_num is greater than $server_number\n";
                    # TODO 3. check that it does not exist in $data->{the_array_name};

                    # 4. replace $setting->{uri} with new value
                    my $new_server = $_;
                    $new_server =~ s/\s+$//;
                    $setting->{uri} = $new_server;
                    last;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# 5. save JSON as a file to disk.
my $filename3 = 'output.json';
open my $proxy_settings, '>', $filename3 or die "Can't open $filename3: $!";
print $proxy_settings encode_json($data);
close $proxy_settings or die "Can't close $proxy_settings: $!";
```

That's the first Perl I have ever written. I don't understand every single line of it 100% yet. (Example: `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";`). I'm sure it is far from optimal, and I'll keep working on it. My question is, **how can it be modified to work with the JSON structure shown above?**

I'm using perl 5, version 30 on Linux.

Comment: eg. prepend `https://` to each URI: `while(my ($key, $value) = each %$data){
        $value->{uri} =~ s{^}{https://}
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;
use utf8;
use strict; use warnings;

my $data = '{
  "0y7vfr1234": {
    "username": "user1@example.com",
    "password": "some-random-password123",
    "uri": "ww1.example.com",
    "index": 14
  },
  "v2rbz1568": {
    "username": "user3@example.com",
    "password": "some-random-password125",
    "uri": "ww3.example.com",
    "index": 29
  },
  "0zjk1156": {
    "username": "user2@example.com",
    "password": "some-random-password124",
    "uri": "ww2.example.com",
    "index": 38
  }
}';

my $json = decode_json $data;

foreach my $key (keys %$json) {
    print "$key\n";
}

print "$json->{v2rbz1568}->{username}\n";
```

### Output

```
v2rbz1568
0y7vfr1234
0zjk1156
user3@example.com
```

Comment: This works fine on sample data, but with the actual data, I get `Can't use string ("d6udq15687339893700") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`.  I think I must not be understanding the dereference operator (->) because I see similar examples that look like print "$json->{v2rbz1568}{username}\n"; How can I determine what is causing my error?

Comment: Then edit new code in your original POST

Comment: I understand the issue a little better now. I will post it as a new question. Your answer is good for this question, so I will leave it as is instead of making it overly complicated.

Comment: My new question is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/557746/268886

Comment: Thank you the "%$json" trick was super useful, it works on my side even if I don't understand the behavior clearly, why can't use directly the "%json".