# Perl - Not a HASH reference or Can't use string ("...") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: linux, perl

I'm learning Perl. I am able to iterate over a JSON collection using a Perl hash data structure like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557613/268886) using sample data. However, the actual data contains some elements that are causing either the error `Not a HASH reference` or `Can't use string ("...") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`.

Here's a simplified example of problematic data that is giving me trouble:

```
{
    "0y7vfr1234": {
        "username": "user1@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password123",
        "uri": "ww1.example.com",
        "index": 14
    },
    "v2rbz1568": {
        "username": "user3@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password125",
        "uri": "ww3.example.com",
        "index": 29
    },
    "active": "0y7vfr1234",
    "0zjk1156": {
        "username": "user2@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password124",
        "uri": "ww2.example.com",
        "index": 38
    },
    "logging": {
        "active": true
    }
}
```

**I am only concerned with the data elements that have a `uri`. I want to skip over the others. How would I do that?**

After trying dozens of things that did not work (and only led to new or different errors), here is how I finally got around the errors. However, I assume there is a much better way to do it than using `ref()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict; use warnings;

my $data = '{
        "0y7vfr1234": {
            "username": "user1@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password123",
            "uri": "ww1.example.com",
            "index": 14
        },
        "v2rbz1568": {
            "username": "user3@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password125",
            "uri": "ww3.example.com",
            "index": 29
        },
        "active": "0y7vfr1234",
        "0zjk1156": {
            "username": "user2@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password124",
            "uri": "ww2.example.com",
            "index": 38
        },
        "logging": {
            "active": true
        }
    }';

my $json = decode_json($data);

foreach my $key (keys %$json) {

    if ( ref( $json->{$key} ) !~ m/HASH/ ) {
            print "[" . ref( $json->{$key} ) . "]: skipping\n";
            next;
    }

    if ( ! exists $json->{$key}->{uri} ) {
        print "Not a server. It's type is:  [" . ref($json->{$key}) . "]\n";
        print "Without curly braces: $json->$key\n";
        print Dumper($json->{$key});
        print "With curly braces: $json->{$key}\n";
        next;
    }

    print "checking $json->{$key}->{uri}\n";
    # do some other stuff
}
```

The code more or less works as is, but I'm not happy with it... or my understanding of it.

My questions are:

1. What is the right way to iterate over "mixed" data like my JSON without encountering errors?
2. What is a good way to display some information about the elements that I skip? I tried various things in the code (Data Dumper, printing without curly braces, etc.) and none of them are satisfactory. Is there a better way I can show information about what was skipped (without causing an error, of course)?
3. Why does the above code `$json->{$key}->{uri}` also work without the arrow like this: `$json->{$key}{uri}`?

I'm using perl 5, version 30 on Linux.

Comment: 1. `ref` is OK. You can also use `reftype` from `Scalar::Util` for blessed references. 2. use `Data::Dumper` or write your own, better variant. 3. because [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it). All of `$a->{b}->{c}`, `$$a{b}{c}`, `$a->{b}{c}`, `$$a{b}->{c}` mean exactly the same. **4. better ask such questions on stackoverflow**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl   
use JSON; use utf8;
use strict; use warnings;

my $data = '{
        "0y7vfr1234": {
            "username": "user1@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password123",
            "uri": "ww1.example.com",
            "index": 14
        },
        "v2rbz1568": {
            "username": "user3@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password125",
            "uri": "ww3.example.com",
            "index": 29
        },
        "active": "0y7vfr1234",
        "0zjk1156": {
            "username": "user2@example.com",
            "password": "some-random-password124",
            "uri": "ww2.example.com",
            "index": 38
        },
        "logging": {
            "active": true
        }
}';   
my $json = decode_json($data);
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%$json)) {
    next unless ref $value;            # skip if $value isn't a ref
    next if scalar (keys %$value) < 2;  # skip if the numbers of HASH keys < 2
    print "$value->{uri}\n";
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.